# How to add event onchange or change in dom element (select ) in tpl ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I need to add the onchange or change event to the select tag inside tpl, I have the following but it does not work. I was trying to create the element with Ext.DomHelper, but I can not find any label to do the append.

Here my code!

```
tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
  '<tpl for=".">',
  ' <div  class="container " style="margin-top:100px;">',
  '     <div class="row">',
  '    <tpl for="' + dataPhrases + '">',
  ' <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-3">',
  '  <div> {[this.getPhraseWithCombobox(values.phrase, values.wordsToChange,xindex)]}</div>',
  '    </div>',
  '    </tpl>',
  '</div>',
  '</div>',
  '</tpl>', {
    getPhraseWithCombobox: function(phrase, words, i) {

      var dh = Ext.DomHelper;
      var f = phrase.split(/[ ]+/);
      var selectList = document.createElement("select");
      selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect" + i);
      selectList.setAttribute("onchange", "myFunction()");

      for (var j = 0; j < valuesCmbx.length; j++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", valuesCmbx[j].id);
        option.text = valuesCmbx[j].text;
        selectList.appendChild(option);
      }
      for (var l = 0; l < words.length; l++) {
        console.log(l);
        f.splice(words[l].pos, 1, selectList.outerHTML);

        str = f.join(" ");
      }

      return str;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi, not sure if you are new to extjs.. but I would recommend looking at combobox. Also, where is your valuesCmbx coming from? Did you mean to pass it as a 4th param? As it stands, your first for loop will never run, since valuesCmbx is undefined

Comment: Sorry, I did not put the complete code. valuesCmbx is an array that is stored in a global variable from data Json. Here is in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ke5) The code is in method showExercises from viewController. Thanks